# Dynamic programming python implementation problem

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I am trying to implement a dynamic programming code using backward iteration. However, the python for loops are giving me list out of range error.

```py
pi = [65,61,42,35,30,32,38,42,53,57,59,64,72,77,64,62,40,64,55,43,40,55,30,21]

#backward recursion
#number of stages T
T = [i for i in range(1,25)]
#possible states
S = [i for i in range(100,1100,100)]
#decision variable
D = [100,-100,0]

#initilaize the value function
obj_val = [[[0 for i in range(1,25)] for j in range(1,9)] for k in range(1,4)]

for t in range(24,0,-1):  #Step backward through problem stages T
    for s in range(9): #Step through each possible stage t state
        for d in range(4):     #step through each feasible stage t decision D
             if t == 24:  #if it is the last stage
                 obj_val[t][s][d] = pi[t]*D[d]
             else: 
                 obj_val[t][s][d] = pi[t]*D[d]+obj_val[t+1][s][d]
```

IndexError: list index out of range (for both the if and else conditions)

Comment: Just a wild guess, you have 24 items in `pi`? Now, look at `obj_val[t+1]`

Comment: I modified the code a bit. Since I am doing backward recursion, for t values other than the final value, it should be able to access values calculated previously. Also, the error is for both the if and else conditions.

Comment: totally unrelated, but `T = [i for i in range(1,25)]` is a rather convoluted (and possibly less efficient) way to write `T = list(range(1, 25))`

Answer (score 0):

In the `obj_val`, the most external array has only 4 objects. So when `if` is true, you can't get the `obj_val[24]`. 
Moreover you don't have index 24 in any of your arrays. It goes maximum to 23.